# Getter properties defined, but not found when used

Tags: c#

I'm working on adapting some existing C# code that contains a class:

```
public class tagTLSEEKINFO
{
    /* Disable variable visibility on debug. */
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private DateTime date;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private string month;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private string year;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private int trunk;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private int addr;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private int subzone;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private tagTLFILETYPE filetype;
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private string path;


public tagTLSEEKINFO()
{
    Path = "";
}

public tagTLSEEKINFO(tagTLFILETYPE filetype)
{
    FileType = filetype;
}

public tagTLSEEKINFO(tagTLFILETYPE filetype, string _path)
{
    Month = "";
    Year = "";
    Trunk = Addr = Subzone = 0;
    FileType = filetype;
    Path = _path;
}

public tagTLSEEKINFO(DateTime date, tagTLFILETYPE filetype)
{
    Date = date;
    Month = date.Month.ToString("00");
    Year = date.Year.ToString().Remove(0, 2);
    Trunk = Addr = Subzone = 0;
    FileType = filetype;
}

public tagTLSEEKINFO(string month, string year, tagTLFILETYPE filetype)
{
    Date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt16(year), Convert.ToInt16(month), 1);
    Month = month;
    Year = year;
    Trunk = Addr = Subzone = 0;
    FileType = filetype;
}

public tagTLSEEKINFO(DateTime date, int trunk, int addr, int subzone)
{
    Date = date;
    Month = date.Month.ToString("00");
    Year = date.Year.ToString().Remove(0, 2);
    Trunk = trunk;
    Addr = addr;
    Subzone = subzone;
    FileType = tagTLFILETYPE.TRENDLOG;
}

public tagTLSEEKINFO(string month, string year, int trunk, int addr, int subzone)
{
    Month = month;
    Year = year;
    Trunk = trunk;
    Addr = addr;
    Subzone = subzone;
    FileType = tagTLFILETYPE.TRENDLOG;
}

public virtual DateTime Date { get { return date; } set { date = value; } }
public virtual string Month { get { return month; } set { month = value; } }
public string Year { get { return year; } set { year = value; } }
public int Trunk { get { return trunk; } set { trunk = value; } }
public int Addr { get { return addr; } set { addr = value; } }
public int Subzone { get { return subzone; } set { subzone = value; } }
public tagTLFILETYPE FileType { get { return filetype; } set { filetype = value; } }
public string Path { get { return path; } set { path = value; } }

}//end class
```

When I try to use the property I need (Date), I get this error:

> Error  CS1061  'tagTLSEEKINFO[]' does not contain a definition for 'Date'                 and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'tagTLSEEKINFO[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) TrendLogFileViewer

Comment: Can you show us the line where you are receiving the error?

Comment: Lacking a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say for sure. But based on the error message, it appears you have an array of `tagTLSEEKINFO` objects and are trying to retrieve the `Date` property value from the array, instead of indexing the array and retrieving the property value from a single element of the array. You can't do that. Figure out which element it is you want to get the value from, and use the appropriate index value to get that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you are trying to use the property `Date` on an array of `tagTLSEEKINFO` objects. Try using a `foreach` loop to access them individually:

```
foreach(var seekInfo in <yourtagTLSEEKINFOArrayVariable>)
{
    seekInfo.Date; //you can access `Date` here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it; I've been programming mostly in Python and I just missed it.